# Azure KeyVault GetSecretAsync.Result.Value error handling

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I have the following line of code to return a secret from a KeyVault

```
string kvSecret = kVClient.GetSecretAsync(azureKeyVaultUrl, secret).Result.Value;
```

While this works as expected, I don't really know well how the **Result.Value** synchronous execution handles runtime errors, exceptions, etc.

I am trying to understand if there is any possibility when I call Result.Value where there is an error and the value returned is not actually the secret but some random error therefore my variable **kvSecret** doesn't contain the right value but something else.

Reason I am asking that is that I want to make sure that if the variable is not null or empty, it will always contain the secret and not other random string.

Comment: If there's an error, you'll get an exception, not a random value. You should never block an asynchronous operation though

Comment: Thanks! If I'll get an error then that's what exactly needed. This code needs to run synchronously for other reasons beyond my control.

Comment: accessing `.Result` is almost always wrong - `string kvSecret = await kVClient.GetSecretAsync(azureKeyVaultUrl, secret);` sounds more likely

Comment: if an exception is thrown, the value of `kvSecret` will be inaccessible; if no exception is thrown, the value is whatever the API returns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the KeyVault client is designed to return an Task with KeyVaultErrorException in case a secret does not exist instead of a failure message\result.

In your case, it blows up because when you call `.Result` it unwraps the exception within the Task and will break the execution flow.

The best way to retrieve secret in KeyVault is wrapping the logic within a Try\Catch block like below:

```
try
{
    var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretPath);
    //... any other logic here ...
}
catch (KeyVaultErrorException kvex)
{
    //handle key not found here
}
catch (HttpRequestException ex)
{
    //handle any other error here if needed
}
```

To make it easier to work with keyvault, I generaly create a class to handle these logic, something like:

```
public class SecretManager
{
    KeyVaultClient client;
    public SecretManager(KeyVaultClient client){ this.client = client; }

    public Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName){
        //here I wrap the logic mentioned above
    }
}
```

.

> The above snipped is from the top of my head, **not a copy from production code**

If you use a logic like above, instead of throwing the exception for secret not found, you make the proper exeption handling and return a null value or a value that represent a not found secret, then you will be able to unwrap the results like expected.